# What do these core-js packages do? (fix-re-wks, task, iter-define, etc)

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a lot of core-js packages included by Babel:
[image]

Some of these are pretty straight forward, e.g. `es6.promise` is obviously a promise polyfill, `_object-create` is obviously a `Object.create` polyfill.

I'd like to know what some of the bigger packages do. Specifically:

1. _fix-re-wks
2. _task
3. _iter-define
4. _redefine
5. _microtask
6. _invoke

This would help because I can stub out unneeded packages. E.g. I stubbed out `symbol` because I don't need the symbol methods, just the symbol constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`core-js` is a modular standard library for JavaScript. It includes polyfills for ECMAScript up to 2019: promises, symbols, collections, iterators, typed arrays, many other features, ECMAScript proposals, some cross-platform WHATWG / W3C features and proposals like URL. You can load only required features or use it without global namespace pollution.

The pieces that you asked about, specifically:

1. _fix-re-wks
2. _task
3. _iter-define
4. _redefine
5. _microtask
6. _invoke

are internal parts of `core-js` like helpers and utils. See the directory for those here:

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/master/packages/core-js/internals